# finding amplitude from displacement graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, odeint

I have been trying to model a problem of forced driven oscillator and plotting the graph for displacement vs time period for various parameter values using scipy.integrate module odeint.

here is the code

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import ipywidgets as ipw
"""
parameters involved
I=moment of inertia of load(cylinder or disc) connected
b=damping constant
s=tortional constant of wire
f0=max driving torque
w=frequency of driving torque 
x=angular deflection of cylinder(taken in place of theta)
x"=d2x/dt2(xddot)
x'=dx/dt(xdot)
equation
I(x")+bx'+sx=f0cos(wt)
x"=(f0/I)cos(wt)-(b/I)x'-(s/I)x
x"=F0cos(wt)-Bx'-Sx

"""
def ode(X, t, B, S, F0, w):
    """
    Free Harmonic Oscillator ODE
    """
    x, xdot = X
    xddot = -B*xdot -S*x + F0 * np.cos(w * t)
    return [xdot, xddot]

def update(B = 0.79, S = 3.21, F0 = 1., w= 1.76):
    """
    Update function.
    """
    X0 = np.zeros(2)
    sol = integrate.odeint(ode, X0, t, args = (B, S, F0, w))
    line0.set_ydata(sol[:, 0])

Nt = 1000
t = np.linspace(0., 100., Nt)
#t=np.exp(np.linspace(0.,100.,Nt))
dummy = np.zeros_like(t)
fig = plt.figure()
line0, = plt.plot(t, dummy, label = "position")
plt.grid()
plt.ylim(-1., 1.)
plt.xlabel("Time, $t$")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude, $a$")
plt.legend()

ipw.interact(update, B = (0., 1., 0.01),
             S = (0, 10, 0.01),
             F0 = (0, 2., 0.05), w = (0,2*np.pi*1,2*np.pi*0.01));
```

I am unable to understand how to plot amplitude vs frequency and phase vs frequency plot from this given code. please help